# Perl one liner to convert epoch to human readable then remove epoch

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

First, some background:

We are using code in our .bash_profile that appends a timestamp to the history command.

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%Y %T "
```

Then we also have code that appends our command history to a specific location in /root/history/

```
export HISTFILE=/root/history/.bash_hist-$(who -m | awk '{print $1}')
```

The "export HISTTIMEFORMAT" command will append the epoch timestamp to the file in /root/history/.

Now the magic happens when we use a perl one-liner to convert the epoch to human readable. (this, btw, is also in .bash_profile)

```
format_history () {
    perl -i -e '$/=undef;my $string=<>;$string=~s/#([0-9]  {10}.*\n.*$)/"# ".localtime($1)."#\n#$1"/ge;print $string;'   /root/history/.bash_hist-$(who -m | awk '{print $1}')
}

shopt -s histappend
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a;format_history;$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

The end result is a file that contains lines like this for each command:

```
# Wed Apr 27 10:11:26 2016
#1461769886
vi /root/.bash_profile
```

I am looking for a way to have perl remove the epoch timestamp once its done converting it but have been unsuccessful so far. I have tried using sed at the end of the line and another perl command. Like this:

First try:

```
 perl -i -e '$/=undef;my $string=<>;$string=~s/#([0-9]{10}.*\n.*$)/"# ".localtime($1)."#\n#$1"/ge;print $string;' /root/history/.bash_hist-$(who -m | awk '{print $1}' | sed '/^#1/ d'
```

Second try:

```
perl -i -e '$/=undef;my $string=<>;$string=~s/#([0-9]{10}.*\n.*$)/"# ".localtime($1)."#\n#$1"/ge;print $string;' /root/history/.bash_hist-$(who -m | awk '{print $1}' | perl -i -nle 'print if !/^#1\b' /root/history/.bash_hist-$(who -m | awk '{print $1}'
```

But as I mentioned these do not work. Can anyone help me find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want the epoch line, why are you writing it?

```
format_history () {
    local file=/root/history/.bash_hist-$LOGNAME
    perl -i -pe 's/^#(\d{10})$/"# ".localtime($1)/e' "$file"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but to avoid printing epoch, you could try removing the `#$1` part, like this:

```
perl -i -e '$/=undef;my $string=<>;$string=~s/#([0-9]  {10}.*\n.*$)/"# ".localtime($1)."#\n"/ge;print $string;'   /root/history/.bash_hist-$(who -m | awk '{print $1}')
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding out your one-liner to make it a bit more readable...

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -i 

$/=undef;
my $string = <>;
$string =~ s{#([0-9]  {10}.*\n.*$)}{"# ".localtime($1)."#\n#$1"}ge;
print $string;
```

`$1` is the original epoch time you captured. On the replacement (right) side of the regex you pass `$1` into `localtime`, but also put it back into the string with `#$1`. So don't. Remove `#$1`.